# AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'

Tags: javascript, powerbi, adal, powerbi-embedded, adal.js

I use [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) and [PowerBI.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) for embedding Power BI Report using "User owns Data" approach. For this purpose, I have registered "Web app / API" application in Azure. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="powerbi.min.js"></script>
<script src="adal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        "use strict";

        var config = {
            instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
            tenant: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', // I put my Directory ID here
            clientId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', // I put Application ID of my Azure Registered App here
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
            redirectUri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize',
            resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
            prompt: 'none',
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            embedUrlBase: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed',
            groupId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', // My Power BI group
            reportId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', // My Power BI report
            response_type:'id_token'
        };

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
        var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);

        authContext.handleWindowCallback();
        if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
            window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
        }

        var user = authContext.getCachedUser();

        if (!user) {
            authContext.login();
        }

        authContext.acquireToken(config.resource, function(error, token) {
            if (error || !token) {
                alert('ADAL error occurred: ' + error);
                console.log('ADAL error occurred: ' + error);
                return;
            }
            config.authToken = token;

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
                var embedUrl = "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId="+ config.reportId +"&groupId="+ config.groupId;
                var pbiconfig = {
                    type: 'report',
                    tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
                    accessToken: config.authToken,
                    embedUrl: embedUrl,
                    id: config.reportId,
                    pageView: 'fitToWidth'
                };
                var pbiconfigmessage = JSON.stringify(pbiconfig);
                var reportContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];
                var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, pbiconfig);
                var report1 = powerbi.get(reportContainer);
                report1.fullscreen();
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

When I am trying to run this code I receive this error:

> AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter:
>   'client_id'

What could be the problem? I provided correct clientId in my config, as you can see.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You have written clientId. Judging from the error message it looks like the field needs to be written as client_id.